# Remove cells containig specific word like "no" bot not words with "nothing"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've removed table rows with

```
jQuery('td:contains(No)').parent().hide();
```

But cells that contain's a word that begin with "No" will also removed.

This is my rendered html code:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="data-table" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
     <col width="25%" />
     <col />
     <tbody>
       <tr>
          <th class="label">Zusatz-Info</th>
          <td class="data">No</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <th class="label">Info</th>
           <td class="data">Nothing</td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery('td:contains(No)').parent().hide();
</script>
```

How can I select only the *td*'s that contains the *No*?

Thanks for help a jQuery newbie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not that directly. One possible solution is to use ***data-*** attribute and [`Attribute Equals Selector`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) like the following way:

```js
jQuery('td[data-flag=No').parent().hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="data-table" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
   <col width="25%" />
   <col />
   <tbody>
     <tr>
        <th class="label">Zusatz-Info</th>
        <td class="data" data-flag="No">No</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <th class="label">Info</th>
         <td class="data" data-flag="Nothing">Nothing</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("td").filter(function() {
      if($(this).text() === "No") {
       $(this).parent().hide();
      }
   });
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table class="data-table" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
   <col width="25%" />
   <col />
   <tbody>
     <tr>
        <th class="label">Zusatz-Info</th>
        <td class="data" data-flag="No">No</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <th class="label">Info</th>
         <td class="data" data-flag="Nothing">Nothing</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("td").filter(function() {
      if($(this).text() === "No") {
        // remove text
        $(this).text('');
        // or hide tr
        $(this).parent().hide();
      }
    });
 });
```

Comment: Hello Fiodorov Andrei,I don't understand your "$" sign. I use jQuery at the beginning. Why you use $? The code I use is from Magento 1.9 Shop - there is also prototype.js, scriptaculous,js and jquery.js. Can you explain where I'm should use jQuery or $?

Comment: Hello. My solution based on html without data attribute.

Comment: This is what I get in Console: **Uncaught TypeError: $(...).text is not a function
    at HTMLTableCellElement.<anonymous> (.html:727)
    at jquery-1.9.1.min.js:4**

Comment: try this:  ```$(document).ready(function() {
    $("td").filter(function(index, cell) {
      if(cell.innerHTML === "No") {
       $(this).parent().hide();
      }
   });
 });```

Comment: Online code [example](https://jsfiddle.net/r3jynhw8/4/)